# Tool to ensure data quality

Tags: data, cloud

I created an ETL in GCP, I process XML file from a bucket, and load them to bigquery.

Sometimes we find that some files are not processed, or they are not in the bigquery dataset.

I created a metric table that contains metadata about processed files, however, I want to automate checks (for example checking that all files in storage exist in the metric table...)

**EDIT**

In short what I want is to be able to compare source and target environment/ compare data before entering the ETL and the data after exiting it, to tell that I didn't forget anything, I could work out some scripts to do that but I wonder if there is something already created.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In GCP you have two tools that can help you organize your pipeline, clean the data and send alerts in case of errors:

- [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer)
- [DataPrep](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep)

Open a ticket with GCP, they might suggest you what is the most suitable solution for you.

**EDIT:** What you are looking for is called [Fuzzy Lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/fuzzy-lookup-transformation?view=sql-server-ver16):

> The Fuzzy Lookup transformation performs data cleaning tasks such as
> standardizing data, correcting data, and providing missing values.

And is present in SSIS.